# Swift - Why is DispatchGroup not working in this function?

Tags: swift, completionhandler, dispatchgroup

I am waiting for `idToken` response before returning the variable.

Please don't tell me to just use completion handler and call it without a `DispatchGroup`. I know I can do that, but I am trying to understand why this logic does not work.

```
func createToken() -> String {
    
    var token = "empty"
    var group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    
    let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
    
    currentUser?.getIDTokenForcingRefresh(true) { idToken, error in
        
        token = idToken ?? "error"
        print("Token Set")
        group.leave()
    }
    
    group.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.now() + 10)

    return token
}
```

Running:

```
print("create ")
print(createToken())
print("done")
```

Output:

```
create 
empty
done
Token Set
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `getIDTokenForcingRefresh` dispatches its completion handler closure back to the main queue, you would see precisely the behavior you describe. When execution hits the `wait` call, it will block the main thread. But if the completion handler closure is being dispatched to the main queue, that will not be able to run until the `wait` call times out and the main thread is freed again.

You can confirm this thesis, that `getIDTokenForcingRefresh` is calling its completion handler on the main thread, in a variety of ways:

- Try removing the `timeout`, in which case this code would completely deadlock if it was using the main queue/thread.
- Print `Thread.isMainThread`.
- Add a precondition statement:

  ```swift
  dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))
  ```
- Set a breakpoint in this closure and let the debugger tell you which thread was used.

But you are quite right: The `wait` pattern should be avoided in general.